# wcf + The content type text/html of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8)

Tags: c#, wcf, utf-8, binding, character-encoding

I'm facing the below error 
"**The content type text/html of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8). 
If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 514 bytes of the response were"**.  below is my bindings and config file

```
  <customBinding>
                <binding name="LoginServiceSoap12Binding">
                    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
                    <httpsTransport />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>

<endpoint address="WCF URL"
             binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="LoginServiceSoap12Binding"
             contract="CWALoginService.LoginServicePortType" name="LoginServiceHttpsSoap12Endpoint" />
```

What is issue not sure i'm facing here...

Answer (score 8):

It most of the time means that your host returns an error page (because the content type is `text/html` as stated) instead of your service returning the response in `application/soap+xml`.

You should check if your service can be activated successfully by going in the url of your service (`http(s)://localhost{:port}/{subSite}/(WCF URL).svc`). If your service can be activated, than the next thing you should try is enabling the wcf tracing in both your client and service side by following:

- Right click your web.config/app.config and click `Edit WCF Configuration`
- Under `Diagnostics` section, enable `Log Auto Flush`, `MessageLogging` and `Tracing` and of course specify a path which your host identity has access to write.
- Check the trace file after you execute that service call. Then you should see the html returned by your host and figure out what the real problem is.